# magento2.2 order status doesnt match status in grid

Tags: magento2, grid, magento2.2.3, order-grid

There is issue for some orders status in grid doesn't match actual order state in order itself, for example order have status "processing", but some why appears as **"pending in grid":**

[image]

same order inside:
[image]

re-indexed, cache flushed.
any suggestions?

Comment: guys, any idea?

Comment: What is payment method? Are you using some extension for 3rd party payment ?

Comment: @Naveed, thanks, it's very good tip! really, all of this "non-matching" orders using third-party payment module. but pls advice how to dig it deeper, because in general this method works fine..

Comment: this could you share your controller folder directory structure ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using some 3rd party module for online payments, There could be possible reason your success or cancel controller files are setting order status ( custom defined ) but these are not created in order status.

How to dig it depper:
In your payment module Controller folder fined "**setStatus**" method, open files where ever this method is called and check what parameter is passed in this method. for example if method is like **setStatus('online-payments')** it means you should have created order status "**online-payments**" in your **System->Order Status** section.

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: thanks again for very valuable input, i'll ask developers to check it. but meanwhile, could you pls briefly explain, why i didn't see in grid same status as i have in order, i cannot get it..

Comment: in order view page, processing status is not set, this would be just showing as default value in drop down. this is what i think would be the scenario.

Comment: in other words - in grid we can see order status, but in order view - order state, right?

Comment: there is chance, because in my guess Processing would be first option in drop down that is why it is showing. Also, there could be state and status issue too